# Conflicting implementations detected with new Command

Tags: java, pousse-cafe

I use [Pousse-Café framework](https://www.pousse-cafe-framework.org/) and started to have a runtime error after creating a new command.

When I try to execute my tests, I get this error:

```
poussecafe.exception.PousseCafeException: Conflicting implementations detected for message interface sbf.iboost.supplychain.model.command.UpdateAvailablity
```

in all tests requiring a Pousse-Café runtime.

Here is the command:

```
@MessageImplementation(message = UpdateAvailablity.class)
public interface UpdateAvailablity extends Command {

    Attribute<UserId> id();

    Attribute<Boolean> availablity();
}
```

and its implementation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@MessageImplementation(message = UpdateAvailablity.class)
public class UpdateAvailablityData implements Serializable, UpdateAvailablity {

    @Override
    public Attribute<UserId> id() {
        return AttributeBuilder
                .stringId(UserId.class)
                .read(() -> id)
                .write(value -> id = value)
                .build();
    }

    private String id;

    @Override
    public Attribute<Boolean> availablity() {
        return AttributeBuilder
                .single(Boolean.class)
                .read(() -> availablity)
                .write(value -> availablity = value)
                .build();
    }

    private boolean availablity;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually coming from the fact that `@MessageImplementation` annotation is used on both the definition (`UpdateAvailablity` class) and the implementation (`UpdateAvailablityData` class) of the command. It should only be present on the implementation. Removing the annotation on the definition solved the problem.